# I am trying to generate a Excel with a helper in cakephp

Tags: php, excel, cakephp

I am using this Cake helper https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel, now I have a lot problem as this:

> Method PhpExcelHelper::createWorksheet does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableHeader does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableRow does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableRow does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableRow does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableFooter does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Missing argument 1 for Helper::output(), called in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\prueba\app\View\Documentos\index.ctp on line 33 and defined [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 806]
>   Undefined variable: str [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 807]
>   Method PhpExcelHelper::exit does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]
>   Model Documento.php

```
<?php
class Documento extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'documento';
}
?>
```

Controller DocumentosController.php

```
<?php
class DocumentosController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','PhpExcel.PhpExcel');
    public function index() {

        $this->set('documentos', $this->Documento->find('all')); 
   }
}
?>
```

This is my view index.ctp

```
<?php  

$this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet();


// define table cells
$table = array(
    array('label' => __('Nombre'), 'filter' => true),
    array('label' => __('Apellido'), 'filter' => true),
    array('label' => __('Edad individuo')),
    array('label' => __('Domicilio'), 'width' => 50, 'wrap' => true),
    array('label' => __('Fecha'))
);

// add heading with different font and bold text
$this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));

// add data
foreach ($documentos as $documento) {
    $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(
        $documento['Documento']['nombre'],
        $documento['Documento']['apellido'],
        $documento['Documento']['edad'],
        $documento['Documento']['domicilio'],
        $documento['Documento']['fecha']
    ));
}

// close table and output
$this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter()
    ->output();

?>
```

Comment: You must include the full error, including line number, and file name that the error reports.

Comment: Usually syntax errors are easy to fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
$this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet();
```

Comment: Call to a member function output() on a non-object

Comment: Try to move that code from the view to the controller. `PhpExcel` is a component that should be included in the controller `public $components = array('PhpExcel')`

Comment: now I have other problem....is this:                                        Call to a member function output() on a non-object

Comment: maybe: `$this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter(); $this->PhpExcel->output();` works?

Comment: Ok thanks but now I have a problem whit this:                          Method PhpExcelHelper::createWorksheet does not exist                 Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableHeader does not exist                  Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableRow does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]

Comment: are you sure your View/Helper/PhpExcelHelper file is ok? (like here https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel/blob/master/View/Helper/PhpExcelHelper.php)

Comment: yes, the file PhpExcelHelper is like.. but the problem is:             ethod PhpExcelHelper::createWorksheet does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]                                  Method PhpExcelHelper::addTableHeader does not exist [CORE\Cake\View\Helper.php, line 192]